# rendering table on screen using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to print a table using angularjs,Since I am new to this so unable to find a better way. I am getting data as shown below

```
$scope.tableDatas = [{"dataMap":
                                {
                                    "INDUSTRIAL":["1","12","34"],
                                    "AXV":["0","18","12"],
                                    "COM":["1","1","3"],
                                    "IND":["1","1","3"],
                                    "IXM":["1","1","3"],
                                    "ADI":["1","1","3"]
                                    }

                                    }] ;
```

I want to print a table where INUSTRIAL,AXV...is a column and other is a data.Please help how Can I render it using Angularjs?

Comment: What have you aready tried?

Comment: angular.forEach(
           $scope.tableDatas,
           function(value, key) {
            var count = value
            .split(",").length;
            var values = value
            .split(",");
            var valuesArr = [];
            valuesObj = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             valuesObj = {
              "name" : values[i]
             }
             valuesArr
               .push(valuesObj);
            }
            console.log(valuesArr);
           }
         )

Comment: put the code in the question not in a comment

Answer (score 0):

check this fiidle may it's what you are looking for

http://jsfiddle.net/t69k62ft/

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.tableDatas = [{"dataMap":
                      {
                          "INDUSTRIAL":["1","12","34"],
                          "AXV":["0","18","12"],
                          "COM":["1","1","3"],
                          "IND":["1","1","3"],
                          "IXM":["1","1","3"],
                          "ADI":["1","1","3"]
                      }
                      
                     }] ;
}
```

```css
td
{border:1px solid #333};
```

```html
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="(k, column) in tableDatas[0].dataMap">{{k}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="(k, column) in tableDatas[0].dataMap">{{column[0]}}
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="(k, column) in tableDatas[0].dataMap">{{column[1]}}
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="(k, column) in tableDatas[0].dataMap">{{column[2]}}
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I add column data dynamically.{{column[0]}}... looks like is not a good option

Answer (score 0):

change html to this if you want dyanamic

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="(k, column) in tableDatas[0].dataMap">{{k}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2]  track by $index">
      <td ng-repeat="(k, column) in tableDatas[0].dataMap">{{column[i]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This could be a start for you, [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/ohddp29x/):

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="(k, column) in tableDatas[0].dataMap">{{k}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="column in tableDatas[0].dataMap">{{column}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can change your array to:

```
$scope.tableDatas = [{"INDUSTRIAL":["1", "12", "34"],
                     {"AXV":["0","18","12"],
                     etc
```

Then in your html something like:

```
<table>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in tableDatas">
           <td ng-repeat="data in row track by $index">
           </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

This would create 6 rows (industrial, axv, etc) and on those rows the data.

If you can't change your array, you could do like:

```
<table>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in tableDatas[0].dataMap">
           <td ng-repeat="data in row track by $index">
           </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can't ng-repeat inside another one you need to use `track by`